# react-scripts and bundle - Are all the 'require' and 'dependencies' added into the final bundle?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle

I am working in a React project that is using react-scripts in its version 3.4.4 among other dependencies and I have to check all the third-party libraries added into the final bundle.

As example, if I check the requires and dependencies from react-scripts in the package-lock.json file:

```
"react-scripts": {
      "version": "3.4.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts/-/react-scripts-3.4.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7J7GZyF/QvZkKAZLneiOIhHozvOMHey7hO9cdO9u68jjhGZlI8hDdOm6UyuHofn6Ajc9Uji5I6Psm/nKNuWdyw==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
        "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
        "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
        "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
        "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
        "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
        "css-loader": "3.4.2",
        "dotenv": "8.2.0",
        "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
        "eslint-loader": "3.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
        "file-loader": "4.3.0",
        "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
        "fsevents": "2.1.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.11",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
        "jest": "24.9.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
        "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
        "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
        "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
        "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
        "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
        "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
        "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
        "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
        "resolve": "1.15.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.2",
        "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
        "semver": "6.3.0",
        "style-loader": "0.23.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "2.3.8",
        "ts-pnp": "1.1.6",
        "url-loader": "2.3.0",
        "webpack": "4.42.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0",
        "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
        "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "fs-extra": {
          "version": "8.1.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fs-extra/-/fs-extra-8.1.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-yhlQgA6mnOJUKOsRUFsgJdQCvkKhcz8tlZG5HBQfReYZy46OwLcY+Zia0mtdHsOo9y/hP+CxMN0TU9QxoOtG4g==",
          "requires": {
            "graceful-fs": "^4.2.0",
            "jsonfile": "^4.0.0",
            "universalify": "^0.1.0"
          }
        },
        "semver": {
          "version": "6.3.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-6.3.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-b39TBaTSfV6yBrapU89p5fKekE2m/NwnDocOVruQFS1/veMgdzuPcnOM34M6CwxW8jH/lxEa5rBoDeUwu5HHTw=="
        }
      }
    },
```

My question is, are all the requires and dependencies such, as example, *webpack-dev-server*, *dotenv*, *sass-loader* added into the final bundle?

Thanks!

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What Webpack ends up including is not something published or reported. Using `react-scripts` alone would seen hundreds of modules and versions being shipped in production. Any library you add on top just adds to that weight.

With tree shaking and build deps, you can't rely upon that `requires` at all. Some of those, like Jest or ESLint, are dev-only. They have no runtime. Others will. Some runtime deps will be shaken out too, so can't rely on just recognizing the lib.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer! The point is that I have to know all the third party libraries added in the bundle so, does it exist any way to know all the libraries added in the final library? Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you have to know all third party libraries added? But no, there's no easy way of figuring that out.

Comment: So I guess I'm in big trouble... I have to know it due to an enumeration of all the source code deployed, including all the third party libraries, must be done... Sad news but thanks so much for your help. I'm trying to match the package-lock.json dependencies  with the result of the bundle analysis with source-map-explorer... but this match operation does not confirm if a library has been added or not....

Comment: That's not possible, no, especially if you're using tree shaking. If you need to account for all dependencies then CRA is not a reasonable choice in tooling. [`react-scripts` alone creates a dependency tree of 1465 modules](http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/react-scripts).

Comment: Wow.... thank so much for your help =) I'll find an heuristic way to achieve this but, with the information that you have provided me, it looks like an imposible task. I invite you to modifiy your answer adding your last comment to mark it as resolved.

Comment: I don't think it's at all possible, at least not accurately, but good luck.